# What is the wavelength of a signal with a continuously increasing frequency?

Tags: optics, wavelength, microscopy

What is the wavelength of a signal continuously decreasing in power (and seemingly decreasing in wavelength)?

This question comes as a consequence of trying to find the correct value for the resolution estimate of a signal of a form similar to the one in the image below, using the following equation:

$$\tag{1}r= 0.66 (C_s \lambda^3)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

where $C_s$ represents the spherical aberration coefficient.

[image]

Comment: If the frequency of the light inreases (over time I assume), the wavelength decreases at the same time. But I guess this isn't what you're asking for. So, could you please clarify what you mean with _continuously increasing frequency_ and what the vertical axis in the plot means?

Answer (score 1):

The "true" resolution properties of a signal, i.e., the ability to discriminate one signal say, $s(t)$ from another that is just a delayed and scaled version of itself, $As(t-\tau)$, depends also not on its wavelength (frequency) but its slopes, ie., on the time derivative of the signal $\frac{ds}{dt}$ and on the prevailing signal to noise ratio. All signals are infinitely resolvable if there is no noise, so your question cannot be simply answered that the resolving power of a signal depends on its wavelength in such and such a manner.

If you wish to know a good estimate for a reasonable SNR then you can start by calculating the so-called matched filter response $f(t) = s(t)\otimes s(T_b-t)$ where $T_b$ is a delay that is large enough so that $s(T_b-\tau)$  become causal but otherwise arbitrary and $\otimes$ denotes convolution.

In other words, the filter response is $s(T_b-t)$ is the causal impulse response of the filter matched to the input signal. The instant where the output of this filter peaks is where the  signal should be samples for it provides the highest achievable SNR and also serves to estimate the resolving power of the signal by estimating the so-called 3dB (half power points) on other side of the peak SNR. For a simple mono-chromatic but otherwise finite pulse this is equivalent to Rayleigh's criterion.

---

Note: If you are only interested in calculating the resolution from the Rayleigh criterion then you can ignore the delay $T_b$ and just calculate the convolution $g(t)=s(t) \otimes s(-t)$ and for then $f(t)=g(t+T_b)$ and notice the causal and both the non-causal filter outputs have the same shape and are just delayed replicas.